# How to find all users subscribed to a topic in spring websockets

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket

When making something like a chat application using Spring Websockets, it is useful to know who all is subscribed to any given topic.  For, e.g. presence data displayed in the clients.

I know that I can implement ApplicationListener and keep my own list of "connected users", but it seems like the library must already be doing this work.

What's the recommended way to get active subscription info from the library directly (and without maintaining my own list in memory or db).

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923461/spring-boot-websockets-how-to-see-subscribers/51113021#51113021

Answer (score 3):

You're right, you could use [ApplicationContext events](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events), but unfortunately those events deal with user sessions events and broker events - so you won't be notified when a user subscribes to a particular topic.

You could do that when using the [SimpleBrokerMessageHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/broker/SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.html), by getting the [SubscriptionRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/broker/SubscriptionRegistry.html). But again, the SimpleMessageBroker is not for production use.

If you're using RabbitMQ, you can get that information from its REST API.

The thing is, this is very specific to the broker implementation, so I'm wondering if a feature like that makes sense in Spring Framework. Could you open a [JIRA issue](http://jira.spring.io) to start the discussion?

Comment: You can create a new issue against the "Spring Framework" (aka SPR) project, with the "Messaging" component. Thanks!

Comment: As of 4.1 we also publish subscribe/unsubscribe events http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events. That's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev  Yes, that looks like the ticket.  In the meantime, Grails is on Spring 4.0 in its 2.4.x versions. Any ideas when using Spring 4.0?

Comment: A ChannelInterceptor on the "clientInboundChannel" and basically keeping track of all subscribe/unsubscribe STOMP messages.

Comment: One question, I am going to use SimpleBrokerMessageHandler in prod code are there threads? You said `SimpleMessageBroker is not for production use.`. Could you elaborate why?

Comment: It's production ready if you only have a single instance of your application. If you have several app instances, then messages can't be shared between instances; that job is done with a "real" message broker like rabbitmq.

Comment: Why SimpleMessageBroker is not for production use?