# Spring Boot + Websocket (SockJS)

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a server that notifies connected clients when changes occur.
For that, I'm using Spring Boot for the server. In order to deliver notifications, each client establish a socket with the server.
I used this guide : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ and it works perfectly. In this example, the client send a message over the socket and the server responds.

1. The problem is that I can't find out a way where the server sends a message to client without having the client to send a message first!
2. Is it possible to list all connected websockets ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answers:

1. The client does not need to send a message but they do have to connect and subscribe.  I am actually doing that myself in an application where a browser connects and subscribes and then starts sending messages.  On the server side you can Autowire a Service (or other Component) with a SimpMessagingTemplate object and then use the convertAndSend family of functions to send things to either a particular user or all subscribers.  If you check out [the portfolio project](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) you can see how it is done with the price.stock topic.  The client connects and subscribes and the server has a scheduled job to send to it.  This service is using a MessageSendingOperations object but you can use SimpMessagingTemplate as mentioned above.  I have this code in our application service:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

   ...
   messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId, destination, jsonMessage);
   ```
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795340/how-to-find-all-users-subscribed-to-a-topic-in-spring-websockets) has some good information on finding all users. It seems like you need to use the events defined in the [Spring documentation on STOMP context events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events) to keep track of things yourself if you want that.  Generally since this is a subscription model you may not need to know who is connected.  You could also build your own topic that you send out a request for all clients to respond to and look for their posts.  I have not done this myself but Rossen (one of the commentors) is one of the main authors of the project so I believe him!

Hopefully this helps.  Let me know.