# Spring SimpleMessageBroker in production code

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I wanted to ask on wider community if Spring SimpleMessageBroker is ready for production use.

My use case is very simple. From my perspective broker in memory will be enough. I don't need to start any rabbit or other messaging service.

What I found is one statement https://stackoverflow.com/a/24907072/1370062 but with no wider explanation. Maybe author said this because at that time spring was in early stages with supporting websocket communication.

Can I use Simple Message Broker? I haven't found any official advices regarding to this in spring documentation. Waiting for advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just one application instance you don't need to use a real message broker. In that case Spring's SimpleMessageBroker is available for production use.

Comment: I took a risk and it is working on production. Everything is fine.

Comment: Hi, We are using the same setup, It works, but when there is a number of users more and they are chatting for say 45 min, then spring boot web socket process get killed may be due to more memory consumptions. Did you face this kind of issue.